# CSS width doesn't add up

Tags: css

I have two `<div>`s inside a parent `<div>`. Both the inner ones are styled with no `padding`, `border` or `margin` and as `width:50%; display:inline-block;`. The outer `<div>` also has no `padding`, etc. Firebug shows the outer `<div>` to be of 1240px width, and each inner one to be 620px. So why do they appear one below the other and not side-by-side? If i lower their width to 618px, it works. Huh?

Comment: How about showing us the page, or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: 620px + 620px + a space (white) character > 1240px

Comment: @Matt Ball +1 jsFiddle is so awesome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`display:inline-block` is inconvenient in the way that it takes in consideration mark-up whitespace when drawing the elements, AFAIK. Try setting `font-size:0` to the parent element if it doesn't have any other text, and set the desired `font-size` for the child elements.

P.S., first try eliminating white-space in the mark-up between the elements, to see if that corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a fairly simple solution, if you have two blocks, A and B and they are the exact same size and you are looking at them straight on and they are lined up perfectly you will only see one block.

You're trying to make something display that doesn't fit inside of the container. You've already solved your problem size the container up or the contents down mildly to fit them together.